# Showing a text input when checkbox is clicked - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm having an issue with this code and I can't figure out whey it's not working.
Essentially, when a checkbox is clicked, the text field in the same li should show up.

I don't want a "hide / show", since this will populate the array with additional fields, so i'm looking at making it fill the div with a new input if the checkbox is selected.

Any ideas where I'm running into an issue?

Here's my html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="practice"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Practice 1" class="input_control" name="practice_areas[id][name]" /> Practice 1</label> <div class="showOrder"></div></li>
    <li class="practice"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Practice 2" class="input_control" name="practice_areas[id][name]"  /> Practice 2</label> <div class="showOrder"></div></li>
    <li class="practice"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Practice 3" class="input_control" name="practice_areas[id][name]"  /> Practice 3</label> <div class="showOrder"></div></li>
    <li class="practice"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Practice 4" class="input_control" name="practice_areas[id][name]"  /> Practice 4</label> <div class="showOrder"></div></li>
    <li class="practice"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Practice 5" class="input_control" name="practice_areas[id][name]"  /> Practice 5</label> <div class="showOrder"></div></li>                 
</ul>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery('li.practice').each(function() {
    jQuery(".input_control", this).click(function() {
        jQuery('.showOrder', this).html('<label>Order: <input type="text" size="2" name="practice_area[id][order]" value="" /></label>');
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: "populate the array with additional fields" what do you mean by this? What array?

Comment: Hi Rick, if you notice I have the text fields setup as an array.  If the item is blank, it will still add items to the array.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `$(selector, context)`, the `.showOrder` element is not within the context of clicked element.

```
$('li.practice .input_control').change(function(){
    var $target = $(this).closest('li').find('.showOrder');
    if (this.checked) {
        $target.html('<label>Order: <input type="text" size="2" name="practice_area[id][order]" value="" /></label>');
    } else {
        $target.empty();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6Fq/1/

Comment: Thanks undefined :)  this works because it removes it as well the checkbox is taken off.

Answer (score 2):

You were incorrectly using your `.input_control` as context for locating your `.showOrder`, I changed your code to use your `li.practice` as context, so do as follows:

```
jQuery('li.practice').each(function() {
    var li = this;
    jQuery(".input_control", this).click(function() {
        jQuery('.showOrder', li).html('<label>Order: <input type="text" size="2" name="practice_area[id][order]" value="" /></label>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson, this did work but I Undefined had it being removed as well.